# installing mariadb 5 on centos 7 Unit mariadb.service failed to load: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, mariadb

I try to install mariadb on centos 7 using official documentation https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum/

I have installed these packages:

```
Installed Packages
MariaDB-server.x86_64                   5.5.47-1.el7.centos             @mariadb
MariaDB-client.x86_64                   5.5.47-1.el7.centos             @mariadb
MariaDB-common.x86_64                   5.5.47-1.el7.centos             @mariadb
```

And I try to start mariadb service using 'systemctl start mariadb' but I always get a error
Failed to issue method call: Unit mariadb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

After rebooting I can login into database as a root. But I can't understand the reason, why there's no mariadb service.

Also I have a MariaDB.repo file like this:

```
# MariaDB 5.5 CentOS repository list - created 2016-01-12 10:44 UTC
# http://mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: Are you missing `mariadb-libs.x86_64` ?

Comment: It's added MariaDB-shared from mariadb repository instead of it. But the problem still the same.

Comment: Also I removed the mariadb repo file and install maria-db from base centos 7 repo. And it will work. Is this a bug? Or is it my mistake with repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at their packages, I can see that they don't include a systemd service file in their 5.5 packages.  They do ship a legacy init script at `/etc/init.d/mysql`, so you could technically just run `systemctl start mysql` and systemd's legacy compatibility will take care of it.

```
$ repoquery --enablerepo mariadb --list MariaDB-server | grep init
/etc/init.d/mysql
```

Me personally, I'd rather stick to the stock CentOS packages, which have a proper systemd service unit file included.  As a general rule, most software projects are the experts on their software, not on RPM packaging best practices.